# Strange issue in Codeigniter when trying to select "product listings" by ID

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a strange issue in Codeigniter. I have a controller and a model to fetch product listings from MySQL. I'm  using the uri-segment functions to fetch the ID and put it into the model to retrieve that specific product listing based on the ID.

**The right URl would be (which works great):**

```
http://example.com/listing/2000
```

**However, when you type:**

```
http://example.com/listing/2000ddd
```

this also works, which it shouldn't.

**On the other hand, if you try to type a charachter before the id-number, it doesn't work.**

```
 http://example.com/listing/ddd2000
```

My controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $listing_id = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $messageinfo = $this->Messages_model->get_messageinfo($listing_id);
    $data["messageinfo"] = $messageinfo; 

    $this->load->view('inc_includes/header');
    $this->load->view('pages_sendmessage/sendmessage', $data);  
    $this->load->view('inc_includes/footer');
}
```

My model:

```
function get_messageinfo($listing_id = NULL)
{
    $this->db->select('
      azzo.listing_ads.listing_ads_id,
      azzo.listing_ads.listing_ads_domain_url,
      azzo.listing_ads.listing_ads_expire,
      azzo.listing_ads.listing_ads_user_id,
      azzo.users.username,
      azzo.listing_ads.listing_ads_outprice
    ');
    $this->db->from('azzo.listing_ads');
    $this->db->join('azzo.users', 'azzo.listing_ads.listing_ads_user_id = azzo.users.id', 'inner');
    $this->db->where('azzo.listing_ads.listing_ads_id', $listing_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();  
    if($query->num_rows() == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return $query->row();
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason behind your problem is - your data($listing_id) is converted to integer type when used in model. When you pass 2000ddd as parameter, you will get 2000, but when you pass ddd2000, you will get 0.

Comment: It makes sense that it's because of the data type, I did not know the integer data type treated characters this way. Instead of using an ID, I'm going to use a customized slug stored in the database for all product listings. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yep, what @Jobayer said... That's PHP performing type casting behind the scenes... So it's taking a guess by how it's being used which in this case, is an integer.

Just be aware that when you allow data entry via a URL or by any user input, it is open to folks trying out all sorts of things. You could test that the segment is meant to be an integer by using is_integer($expected_integer_variable_to_check) and take the appropriate action like even just ignoring it...